# Encoder into Decoding Strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string, decode, encode

Using a hand-made code, this is suppose to make the user's input encoded into something different (the letter right after the letter they typed). Whenever I try to run it, the  returns are only the user's sentence. I'm happy it works for the decoder, but the encoder needs to encode the message. I'm wondering why it's not working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EncoderDecoder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a sentence. No numbers, smybols, or punctuations.");
            string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();


            Console.WriteLine("Your encoded message.");
            string encodedSentence = Encode(sentence);
            Console.WriteLine(encodedSentence);

            Console.WriteLine("Your decoded message. Also known as your original message.");
            string decodedSentence = Decode(sentence);
            Console.WriteLine(decodedSentence);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string Decode(string encodedSentence)
        {
            char[] wordArray;
            string[] words = encodedSentence.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i > words.Length; i++)
            {
                wordArray = words[i].ToArray();
                if (wordArray.Length > 1)
                {
                    char beginLetter = wordArray[0];
                    wordArray[0] = wordArray[wordArray.Length + 1];
                    wordArray[wordArray.Length + 1] = beginLetter;
                }
                for (int t = 0; t < wordArray.Length; t++)
                {
                    wordArray[t] = (char)(wordArray[t] + 1);
                }
                words[i] = new string(wordArray);
            }
            string decoded = string.Join(" ", words);
            return decoded;
        }

        private static string Encode(string sentence)
        {
            char[] wordArray;
            string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i > words.Length; i++)
            {
                wordArray = words[i].ToArray();
                if (wordArray.Length > 1)
                {
                    char beginLetter = wordArray[0];
                    wordArray[0] = wordArray[wordArray.Length - 1];
                    wordArray[wordArray.Length - 1] = beginLetter;
                }
                for(int t = 0; t > wordArray.Length; t++)
                {
                    wordArray[t] = (char)(wordArray[t] + 1);
                }
                words[i] = new string(wordArray);
            }
            string encoded = string.Join(" ", words);
            return encoded;
        }

    }
 }
```

Using the arrays, I split the string into the array and then use that array to individually alter the letters. For some reason it's not working...

Answer (score 1):

Both for's are wrong, try: `for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)`

Comment: Ah. That fixed it. it seems i got the signs mixed up for this code. Thank you.

Comment: @TommyVidrio Accept his answer if helped you !

Answer (score 0):

In the encoder in your for loop you've got where t > word array.length should this be less than

Comment: I just fixed that and it did not change it. i still got the same message as the user inputs